# Cómo reducir archivo msdb.mdf

Tags: sql-server

buenos días a la comunidad.

Quisiera pedir su ayuda porque no encuentro mucha información en la red sobre cómo reducir el tamaño del archivo MSDBData.mdf.

Se que es un archivo del sistema pero actualmente pesa casi 200 GB y desconozco por qué pesa tanto, dejo una imágen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay algún script o herramienta dentro del Sql Manager para esto? probé con la opcion de reducir el archivo pero no pasa nada.

Por si acaso, el SQL que se tiene montado es una base de datos que solo se encarga de recibir información, no se envían correos ni nada especial

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Literalmente 10 segundos de búsqueda en google: https://blogs.sap.com/2023/08/03/shrink-the-size-of-data-and-log-file-of-msdb-database-in-sql-server-using-ssms/

Comment: y literalmente no me sirve, ya probé haciendo un shrink al mdf y ldf y no funciona, lo escribi.